# Referencing the selection in deactivated Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

I'd like to copy the selection in the deactivated workbook. But this doesn't work, indeed, I got a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

### Damn! It *is* possible!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

  ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

**Explanation:**

Both ActiveSheet and Selection are children objects of the Application object, not the Workshet or Workbook objects. (See MSDN: [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) and [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx).) Selection means the currently selected item in the active window. Same for ActiveSheet.

Now it turns out that you *can* specify a **window** object for both of them. Normally every Workbook has one window, but you can create multiple windows for each open workbook. Anyhow, every open workbook that you can click and select will have at least one window. This is `whateverworkbook.Windows(1)`.

`ThisWorkbook` always references the workbook running the macro (that means the workbook actually containing the VBA code). In your case, that is the one you are leaving. (Unless you want the macro to run from any workbook you are deactivating, in which case you'd have to come up with a custom event handler that catches each workbook deactivate event...)

And that's it, really. You **can** reference a selection in another workbook, you just have to attack it through it's `Window`.

Thanks for the good question, I have learned something very valuable today. :)

Comment: 1. Do you mean that in a dot-linked statement, ActiveSheet and Selection need always be the first terms? And even ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, and ActiveSheet.Selection seem not correct? 2. Also, in your code, ThisWorkbook is the old workbook and ActiveWorkbook is the new workbook, is that right? 3. I wonder if the use of EnableEvents is because that newwb.Activate redeactives old workbook.

Comment: Why "avoid flicker" doesn't work on my computer? To understand your code, I first commented the 4th line (EnableEvents = False), then I activated a new workbook to trigger the program. Turns out, in the loop, I can see flicker between old and new sheets!!! Even without commenting the 4th line, there is flicker. But it's hard to see since you only redeactive once (this is also why I commented your 4th line first to make flicker obvious).

Comment: @NicholasLiu I have reworked my answer. I was surprised to see that this worked, but it did. Now, about your comments: 1. I have answered this in the new answer. 2. Correct. 3. Correct again, it would otherwise cause an endless loop - try it with F8. :) Flicker - no idea, same for me. It is not supposed to flicker, but it does. Maybe window change happens outside of Excel's jurisdiction, hence Excel's ScreenUpdating has no effect over it? Just guessing here though...